# How do I get a data value into a link

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

```
<td>{{ page.url }}</td>
<td>
  <b-button href="#wiki/{{page.url}}" variant="primary">View</b-button>
</td>
```

I am trying to populate the href on my button.

I also have a router trying to do this

```
 <script>
 const router = new VueRouter({
     routes:[{
       path : '/:id',
       name : 'wiki',
       component : Detail
       }
     ]
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v-bind` or the colon shortcut

```
<b-button :href="'#wiki/' + page.url">
```